# File information while HOVERING over element

Tags: javascript, html, data-transfer

I'm working on a webpage for managing files. For a feature I need to know the file name when hovering a file over a element. It's important to get this information while HOVERING not when "dropping" the file.

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3z2dobt2/4/) with the setup. When you hover a file over the marked div you constantly get some information about the filetype.

You can get the dataTransfer from the hovering event

```
let transfer = event.dataTransfer;
```

The item property contains the file's MIME type.

```
transfer.items
```

However, you don't get full information about the file (name, size, ...).

```
transfer.files
```

When dropping the file i get full informaton about the file

```
transfer.files.lenght //Equal to amount of files dropped
```

I read in a few old posts (< 2008) that this might be a security reason, which I don't understand. There is basically no difference between hovering a file or dropping a file (apart from releasing your LMB).

Thanks your help :)

Comment: The difference is that the user can be dragging a nude picture of them that was standing right beside a picture of their dog, and realize that before they drop the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the protection system, it would mean a website could track everything you drag over it. Let's say you want to move a file from your finder to someplace else and your browser is in the path. Or you drag some text from word to some other app, and you happen to go even for just a short while over your browser window. Your website could access all these contents, without the user wanting to interact with it.

The mouse release is a voluntary action from the user, making it clear that he wants to transfer whichever data he is dragging to the specific web page.

Note that if you control the **dragstart**, you can get the info. But if your page is not the actual agent beginning the drag, then you can not assume until the item is dropped, that the user wants the content visible to your page.

Comment: Not the answer i was hoping for but thanks nonetheless.